# Using js scripts in handlebars?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I'm having trouble loading js scripts into handlebars. I know the code I have is wrong, but not sure how I'm supposed to approach? I've included the code for your reference. Can someone point me in the right direction of how I can get handlebars to include the js in the html and execute?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Passionfruit App Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../site/css/screen.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../site/css/cupertino/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="data">
        <form id="addData" action="#">
            <div>
                <label for="coverImage">CoverImage: </label><input id="coverImage" type="file" />
                <label for="title">Title: </label><input id="title" type="text" />
                <label for="author">Author: </label><input id="author" type="text" />
                <label for="releaseDate">Release date: </label><input id="releaseDate" type="text" />
                <label for="keywords">Keywords: </label><input id="keywords" type="text" />
                <button id="add">Add</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script id="dataTemplate" type="text/template">
        <img src="<%= coverImage %>"/>
        <ul>
            <li><%= title %></li>
            <li><%= author %></li>
            <li><%= isNaN(releaseDate) ? releaseDate : $.format.date(new Date(Number(releaseDate)), 'MMMM yyyy') %></li>
            <li><% _.each( keywords, function( keyobj ) {%> <%= keyobj.keyword %><% } ); %></li>
        </ul>

        <button class="delete">Delete</button>
    </script>
    <script src="../site/js/lib/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
    <script src="../site/js/lib/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.js"></script>
    <script src="../site/js/lib/jquery-dateFormat-1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="../site/js/lib/underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="../site/js/lib/backbone.js"></script>
    <script src="../site/js/models/data.js"></script>
    <script src="../site/js/collections/library.js"></script>
    <script src="../site/js/views/data.js"></script>
    <script src="../site/js/views/library.js"></script>
    <script src="../site/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: The answer I linked explains that handlebars is designed to be logicless. See the answer for alternatives that do support logic. However, the idea would be that you would pass that as data into the template instead of having JS figure out what to output. That is, run that JavaScript outside of the template and pass an already processed list that can be used by the template without custom logic.

Comment: Thanks for the response Juan, would you be able to tell me more clearly how I might able implement your idea?